# How to invoke multiple instances of a java program at the same time

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, launcher

I have a Java program and I am trying to write a launcher program for it so that it can invoke the main method of the first program parallel at the same time multiple times as specified in the loop condition. I tried with Runnable method but did not work. Any help appreciated.

The below code is throwing An unknown exception :java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

```
    public class JavaLauncher {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for(int i=1; i<=40; i++) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                   try{
                       JavaProgram1.main(args);
                   } catch(Exception e) {
                       System.out.println("An unknown exception :" + e.toString());
                   }
                }
              }).start();
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add your code. So that only We can understand

Comment: Without code, your question is not really clear. If you "tried with Runnable", it sounds like you are not trying to run your program multiple times in parallel but actually one class in multiple threads. Also what does "but did not work" mean?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you write your launcher inside main and that will invoke your functional class methods. For multiple times invoking a method you can use loop here in main.

Comment: I wanted to start parallel instances of the program at the same time

Comment: @sijo would you please be clear about "same time", 2 statements will not get executed at "same time". Even if you create 2 threads then they would not execute same code at "same time" because cpu would let them execute on the bases of time slicing. You will have to do synchronization . If you let us know your purpose/problem in wider way then you can definitely get help.